# Unable to scrape video (zoom streaming)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape a video from a website. I have used the below code to scrape the video but the code doesn't work and doesn't give any error too. Any help much appreciated.

Python code below:

```
new_download_url = e_url+'?access_token=' + zoom_access_token

try:
    response = requests.get(new_download_url, stream=True)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
    print(repr(err))
    response = requests.get(new_download_url, stream=True)
try:
    with open(full_filename, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
            if chunk:
                fd.write(chunk)
                fd.flush()
                os.fsync(fd.fileno())
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What page are you referring to on your zoom account ? the recordings ? Zoom has [an api](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/introduction), you can checkout the multiple [authentication methods](https://marketplace.zoom.us/develop/create). Or maybe you're already using the API, what does `e_url` look like ? Where does `zoom_access_token` come from ?